# Android Webservice Session Managment

Tags: android, service, web

I m working on an android application consuming webservices. At first the app logins through the httppost method written below.

```
public void postData() throws ParseException, IOException 
{
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.46:8080/login");
    httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");;
    HttpResponse responses = null;

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LoginForm[email]", "t@a.com"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LoginForm[password]", "tttttt"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    responses = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    HttpEntity responseEntity = responses.getEntity();
    String apitoken = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);

}
```

Now the apitoken is the key(seesion key) which will return the service other data about that user

```
public void getCategories {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.46:8080/usercategories");
          httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");;


          HttpResponse responses = null;
          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_token", apitoken));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

         try {
              responses = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          }


         HttpEntity responseEntity = responses.getEntity();
        String category =EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity) ;
}
}
```

Now the problem is that on the server session key (api_token) is not getting recoginsed..
I have checked at the server that is exactly the same key which the app got from the server. 
I have implemented the same webservice in iPhone. which works fine.. 
I m new to android , I don't understand whats the problem. Should i also maintain session at client side or something else.
Any help will be welcome